# How to define if two infinite sets have the same cardinality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory

I am learning about cardinality of infinite sets and it seems a bit confusing to me to identify given two sets.

Per say how can I identify if

$S_1= -\{\frac{1}{n}\mid \in\mathbb N\}$ and $S_2= -\{\frac{1}{2n}\mid \in\mathbb N\}$ have the same cardinality.

How can I write a function that can map from s1 to s2. Any tricks so this can be more intuitive? All I know is that the function has to be bijective.

Comment: $S_1\to S_2,\;x\mapsto x/2$ is an obvious (?) bijection.

Comment: Why does your confusion amount to ambiguity? I don't understand why you chose the complaint that it seems ambiguous. Not being able to find the function doesn't make it ambiguous.

Comment: It is not a complaint rather a comment that for me just at looking at it seems that there is no function to map from s1 to s2 but what if it is otherwise?

Comment: Do you really mean $1/2n=\frac12n,$ or do you mean $1/(2n)=\frac1{2n}?$

Comment: @Ran123 OK, now that you know the function, does it look at least _obvious in retrospect_?

Comment: I edited the expressions and notice there is a negative on front. I am not familiar with Latex sorry for the confusion

Comment: For instance, do you understand the bijection between the natural numbers and the even natural numbers? This is the same thing only with their (negative?) reciprocals. (Speaking of the negative thing, did you mean to put the minus sign inside the curly braces?)

Comment: The negative is on the outside otherwise I understand the bijection, so what would the negative do to the expressions? In other cases how can one identify if two sets do not have the same cardinality?

Comment: @Ran123 well, what does the negative on the outside *mean*? The way I’d interpret the notation is that it means the same thing as with the negative on the inside, but it’s possible you have a different definiton.

Comment: What would be an example of sets that are infinite and do not have the same cardinality?

Comment: @Ran123 [the real numbers and the natural numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument). If you mean subsets of the natural numbers or rational numbers, then there aren’t any: any infinite subset of a countably infinite set is countably infinite.

Comment: So the natural numbers and rational numbers have the same cardinality because they are countably infinite and N is a subset of Q.

Comment: The natural numbers and rational numbers have the same cardinality because there exists a bijection between them. They are countably infinite because that is the name we use to describe sets that are bijective with the natural numbers. The natural numbers and the real numbers have different cardinalities because there is no bijection between them, which we know by Cantor's diagonal argument.